# Gulp error in WebStorm: Failed to list gulp tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, webstorm

My WebStorm has stopped read and run gulp tasks.

It was working fine until last Friday.

This is an error that appears in console:

> Failed to list gulp tasks in questionary/gulpfile.js: Failed to parse
>   JSON -> Unterminated array at line 1 column 5 path $[1]  * Edit
>   settings
>
> $ /usr/local/bin/node
>   /Users/rkon2006/Projects/My/questionary/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
>   --no-color --gulpfile /Users/rkon2006/Projects/My/questionary/gulpfile.js --tasks-json
>   [17:26:14] Using gulpfile ~/Projects/My/questionary/gulpfile.js
>   [17:26:14] Starting 'default'... Default task...

This is the code from my gulpfile.js (it doesn't start even with this code):

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    console.log('Default task...');
});
```

Process finished with exit code 0

I use gulp v4.0, node js 4.1.1 (tried defferent versions from 0.10.28 up to 4.1.1) and npm 2.14.4.

Do you have any ideas about this?

Answer (score 18):

I have the same problem with webstorm after install a updated version of node.
The solution for me is the following:

In the block Gulp where **webstorm show the list of task**, **click the cog icon** and **select gulp settings**, in the section **"Gulp package"** add the path to the **local gulp package**(the gulp inside the node_modules in your project).

Example of path: **yourproject\node_modules\gulp**

Comment: Another way that would probably solve the problem is to remove the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`  again.

You must have your dependencies registered in the `package.json` file

Comment: The problem was that InelliJ was not recognizing my global gulp. I just referenced it to my node_modules/gulp folder and it worked without any problems

Answer (score 3):

Update node version and npm itself, that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that some text is logged to standard output stream when evaluating gulpfile.js, but before running any gulp task (i.e. logging happens outside of gulp tasks); 
possible workarounds:

- Avoid logging anything to standard output stream outside of gulp
  tasks.

Or

- Don't log to standard output stream if it's started for listing
  tasks, like:

> ```
> if (!isListingTasks()) {
>     console.log('[my info]');
> }
>
> function isListingTasks() {
>     return process.argv[process.argv.length - 1] === '--tasks-json';
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem and it was fixed by selecting different Node Interpreter version e.g. in the below image I selected 8.9.2 and then clicked small refresh button in Gulp window and the issue was fixed.

[image]